# How to check an image is available or not in a page by using its id - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to check weather an image is available or not using jquery.

For example :

1. I have an image whose ID is image1. In some pages this image is available and not available in some pages.
2. I need to check in the page weather the image is available. If image is not available i will run a script.
3. How can i achieve it using jquery.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: yeah store pages into `div ` and search that id into that `div`

Comment: define *"available"* ... element exists or it's `src` is available? Please take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`error`](http://api.jquery.com/error/) like this:

```
$('#image_id').error(function() {
  alert('Image does not exist !!');
});
```

> If the image cannot be loaded (for example, because it is not present
>   at the supplied URL), the alert is displayed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: if ((window.universal_variable.product.unit_sale_price ==  window.universal_variable.product.unit_price) && $('#image_id').error(function() ) {
      cb()
    }

Comment: i have to add another condition to add. how can i add this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```
if  (!document.getElementById("lpg"))){
  do something();
  }
```